# Python beautiful soup retrieve image from html

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using python's beautifulSoup package to scrape the following page: https://www.nike.com/w/womens-shoes-5e1x6zy7ok

When I use the following code:

```
data = br.open("https://www.nike.com/w/womens-shoes-5e1x6zy7ok").read()
soup = BS(data)
shoes = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'product-card__body'})
```

I receive only:

```
<picture><source media="0" srcset=""/><source media="1" srcset=""/><source media="2" srcset=""/><img alt="Nike Air Max 2090 Women's Shoe" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"/></picture>
```

However, if I copy directly from the site's URL, I receive much more information:

```
<picture><source srcset="product-card__body" media="(min-width: 1024px)"><source srcset="https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_592,f_auto/t_product_v1/b2bfaf14-ed59-48a7-b8ae-e684b1d605ce/air-max-270-react-se-womens-shoe-6bhhrf.jpg" media="(max-width: 1023px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi)"><source srcset="https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_318,f_auto/t_product_v1/b2bfaf14-ed59-48a7-b8ae-e684b1d605ce/air-max-270-react-se-womens-shoe-6bhhrf.jpg" media="(max-width: 1023px)"><img src="https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_318,f_auto/t_product_v1/b2bfaf14-ed59-48a7-b8ae-e684b1d605ce/air-max-270-react-se-womens-shoe-6bhhrf.jpg" alt="Nike Air Max 270 React SE Women's Shoe"></picture>
```

How do I use beautifulsoup to obtain the latter information?

Comment: What information are you trying to get? The titles of all the images on the page? just the first title?

Comment: Really all information associated with each shoe, including the image of the shoe @Mendelg

Comment: What is this `br.open` you're using? What are those `picture` elements? I've tried with requests + bs4 and I get exactly what I'm supposed to from the link

Answer (score 1):

The data is loaded via JavaScript from their API. This script will print the initial products on the page:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.nike.com/gb/w/womens-shoes-5e1x6zy7ok'
html_data = requests.get(url).text
data = json.loads(re.search(r'window.INITIAL_REDUX_STATE=(\{.*?\});', html_data).group(1))
   
for p in data['Wall']['products']:
    print(p['title'])
    print(p['subtitle'])
    print(p['price']['currentPrice'], p['price']['currency'])
    print(p['colorways'][0]['images']['portraitURL'].replace('w_400', 'w_1920'))
    print('-' * 120)
```

Prints:

```
Nike Air VaporMax 2020 FK
Women's Shoe
189.95 GBP
https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_1920,f_auto/t_product_v1/d4452769-d6ac-4121-8f98-96f7cb9e0f68/image.jpg
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nike Air Max 90
Women's Shoe
114.95 GBP
https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_1920,f_auto/t_product_v1/e4182f87-d936-4052-a14a-b3c8bd161a38/image.jpg
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NikeCourt Air Zoom GP Turbo
Women's Hard Court Tennis Shoe
124.95 GBP
https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_1920,f_auto/t_product_v1/4ec4011a-1c46-42f4-9b4b-ff99fd9592f2/image.jpg
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nike Air Zoom SuperRep Premium
Women's HIIT Class Shoe
114.95 GBP
https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_1920,f_auto/t_product_v1/d058f141-eebb-4578-bc87-53867c9ee173/image.jpg
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

---

EDIT: TO print products form all pages:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.nike.com/gb/w/womens-shoes-5e1x6zy7ok'
html_data = requests.get(url).text
data = json.loads(re.search(r'window.INITIAL_REDUX_STATE=(\{.*?\});', html_data).group(1))

for p in data['Wall']['products']:
    print(p['title'])
    print(p['subtitle'])
    print(p['price']['currentPrice'], p['price']['currency'])
    print(p['colorways'][0]['images']['portraitURL'].replace('w_400', 'w_1920'))
    print('-' * 120)

next_page = data['Wall']['pageData']['next']
while next_page:
    u = 'https://www.nike.com' + next_page

    data = requests.get(u).json()
    for o in data['objects']:
        p = o['productInfo'][0]
        print(p['productContent']['title'])
        print(p['productContent']['subtitle'])
        print(p['merchPrice']['currentPrice'], p['merchPrice']['currency'])
        print(p['imageUrls']['productImageUrl'])
        print('-' * 120)

    next_page = data.get('pages', {'next':''})['next']
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, how do I get the shoes on different pages?

Comment: @Anjrej Kesely How do I append the new shoes, on the next pages, to the original shoes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62988117/webscraping-information-off-website-using-python-requests @Anjrej Kesely

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests
...
req = requests.get(<your URL>, headers={'User-Agent': <user-agent from your browser>})
if not req.ok:
    # Error
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text)
...
```