# Webscraping information off website using python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, jinja2

Webscraping https://www.nike.com/w/mens-shoes-nik1zy7ok for shoes. Right now I can retrieve the shoes that initially load, and also the shoes that load as you scroll to the next page with the following code:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.nike.com/gb/w/womens-shoes-5e1x6zy7ok'
html_data = requests.get(url).text
data = json.loads(re.search(r'window.INITIAL_REDUX_STATE=(\{.*?\});', html_data).group(1))

for p in data['Wall']['products']:
    print(p['title'])
    print(p['subtitle'])
    print(p['price']['currentPrice'], p['price']['currency'])
    print(p['colorways'][0]['images']['portraitURL'].replace('w_400', 'w_1920'))
    print('-' * 120)

next_page = data['Wall']['pageData']['next']
while next_page:
    u = 'https://www.nike.com' + next_page

    data = requests.get(u).json()
    for o in data['objects']:
        p = o['productInfo'][0]
        print(p['productContent']['title'])
        print(p['productContent']['subtitle'])
        print(p['merchPrice']['currentPrice'], p['merchPrice']['currency'])
        print(p['imageUrls']['productImageUrl'])
        print('-' * 120)

    next_page = data.get('pages', {'next':''})['next']
```

How do I append all these shoes together to form a dictionary that I can print results using:

```
{% for shoe in shoes['Wall']['products'] %}
    <p>{{shoe}}</p>
    <h2>New shoe</h2>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive generator function that gets the job done in a pinch, but it's a bit messy. This really needs quite a lot more to be production code, like handling request errors etc, but it should get you headed in the right direction. Do ask questions if anything is confusing, there are some difficult to understand concepts here for the uninitiated.

```py
import re
import json
import requests


def get_shoes(url="https://www.nike.com/", path=None):
    response = requests.get(f"{url}{path}")

    try:
        data = response.json()
        products = (
            {
                "title": p["productContent"]["title"],
                "subtitle": p["productContent"]["subtitle"],
                "price": p["merchPrice"]["currentPrice"],
                "currency": p["merchPrice"]["currency"],
                "image_url": p["imageUrls"]["productImageUrl"],
            }
            for i in data["objects"]
            for p in i["productInfo"]
        )
        next_page = data.get("pages", {"next": ""})["next"]

    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        data = json.loads(
            re.search(r"window.INITIAL_REDUX_STATE=(\{.*?\});", response.text).group(1)
        )
        products = (
            {
                "title": p["title"],
                "subtitle": p["subtitle"],
                "price": p["price"]["currentPrice"],
                "currency": p["price"]["currency"],
                "image_url": p["colorways"][0]["images"]["portraitURL"].replace(
                    "w_400", "w_1920"
                ),
            }
            for p in data["Wall"]["products"]
        )
        next_page = data["Wall"]["pageData"]["next"]

    for product in products:
        yield product

    if next_page:
        yield from get_shoes(url, next_page)


shoes = {}

for shoe in get_shoes(path="gb/w/womens-shoes-5e1x6zy7ok"):
    print(shoe["title"])
    print(shoe["subtitle"])
    print(shoe["price"], shoe["currency"])
    print(shoe["image_url"])
    print("-" * 120)
```

Comment: Could you include all information associated with each shoe? Not just title, subtitle, price, currency, and image url

Comment: You certainly could, but that wasn't the expected outcome of your original question given the Liquid template you proposed.

Comment: Fair point, can you give a look at this other question I proposed : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62999427/how-to-webscrape-all-shoes-on-nike-page-using-python?noredirect=1#comment111408442_62999427