# How to webscrape all shoes on nike page using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to webscrape all the shoes on https://www.nike.com/w/mens-shoes-nik1zy7ok. How do I scrape all the shoes including the shoes that load as you scroll down the page?

The exact information I want to obtain is inside the div elements with the class "product-card__body"
as follows:

```
<div class="product-card__body " data-el-type="Card"><figure><a class="product-card__link-overlay" href="https://www.nike.com/t/air-force-1-07-mens-shoe-TjqcX1/CJ0952-001">Nike Air Force 1 '07</a><a class="product-card__img-link-overlay" href="https://www.nike.com/t/air-force-1-07-mens-shoe-TjqcX1/CJ0952-001" aria-describedby="Nike Air Force 1 '07" data-el-type="Hero"><div class="image-loader css-zrrhrw product-card__hero-image is--loaded"><picture><source srcset="https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_592,f_auto/t_product_v1/s12ff321cn2nykxhva9j/air-force-1-07-mens-shoe-TjqcX1.jpg" media="(min-width: 1024px)"><source srcset="https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_592,f_auto/t_product_v1/s12ff321cn2nykxhva9j/air-force-1-07-mens-shoe-TjqcX1.jpg" media="(max-width: 1023px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi)"><source srcset="https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_318,f_auto/t_product_v1/s12ff321cn2nykxhva9j/air-force-1-07-mens-shoe-TjqcX1.jpg" media="(max-width: 1023px)"><img src="https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_318,f_auto/t_product_v1/s12ff321cn2nykxhva9j/air-force-1-07-mens-shoe-TjqcX1.jpg" alt="Nike Air Force 1 '07 Men's Shoe"></picture></div></a><div class="product-card__info"><div class="product_msg_info"><div class="product-card__titles"><div class="product-card__title " id="Nike Air Force 1 '07">Nike Air Force 1 '07</div><div class="product-card__subtitle ">Men's Shoe</div></div></div><div class="product-card__count-wrapper show--all"><div class="product-card__count-item"><button type="button" aria-expanded="false" class="product-card__colorway-btn"><div aria-label="Available in 3 Colors" aria-describedby="Nike Air Force 1 '07" class="product-card__product-count "><span>3 Colors</span></div></button></div></div><div class="product-card__price-wrapper "><div class="product-card__price"><div><div class="product-price css-11s12ax is--current-price" data-test="product-price">$90</div></div></div></div></div></figure></div>
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
    html_data = requests.get("https://www.nike.com/w/mens-shoes-nik1zy7ok").text
    shoes = json.loads(re.search(r'window.INITIAL_REDUX_STATE=(\{.*?\});', html_data).group(1))
```

Right now it only retrieves the shoes that initially load on the page. How do I get the rest of the shoes as well and append that to the shoes variable?

Comment: Judging by the tags you used, you already know about `BeautifulSoup` and `requests`, so you're ready to implement this. What code have you written and where exactly are you facing issues?

Comment: @ForceBru check edit

Comment: requests.get() will fetch a html page. The shoes are loaded onto the page by JavaScript. You'll may be able to call the APIs directly (use dev tools to examine requests & Postman to see if you can call it). Or use a package like selenium.

Comment: Hi Greg, how do I figure out the API URL to call?

Answer (score 1):

By examining the API calls made by the website you can find a cryptic URL starting with https://api.nike.com/. This URL is also stored in the `INITIAL_REDUX_STATE` that you already used to get the first couple of products. So, I simply extend your approach:

```
import requests
import json
import re

# your product page
uri = 'https://www.nike.com/w/mens-shoes-nik1zy7ok'

base_url = 'https://api.nike.com'
session = requests.Session()

def get_lazy_products(stub, products):
"""Get the lazily loaded products."""
    response = session.get(base_url + stub).json()
    next_products = response['pages']['next']
    products += response['objects']
    if next_products:
        get_lazy_products(next_products, products)
    return products

# find INITIAL_REDUX_STATE
html_data = session.get(uri).text
redux = json.loads(re.search(r'window.INITIAL_REDUX_STATE=(\{.*?\});', html_data).group(1))

# find the initial products and the api entry point for the recursive loading of additional products
wall = redux['Wall']
initial_products = re.sub('anchor=[0-9]+', 'anchor=0', wall['pageData']['next'])

# find all the products
products = get_lazy_products(initial_products, [])

# Optional: filter by id to get a list with unique products
cloudProductIds = set()
unique_products = []
for product in products:
    try:
        if not product['id'] in cloudProductIds:
            cloudProductIds.add(product['id'])
            unique_products.append(product)
    except KeyError:
        print(product)
```

The api also returns the total number of products, though this number seems to vary and depend on the `count` parameter in the api`s URL.

Do you need help parsing or aggregating the results?

Comment: This is great, but how do I specify whether I want mens' or womens' shoes?

Comment: I just edited my previous approach so you can use a URL as entry point (like https://www.nike.com/w/mens-shoes-nik1zy7ok) and then find all the products.

Comment: Thank you, but I keep receiving this error: redux = [script for script in scripts if script.text.startswith('window.INITIAL_REDUX_STATE')][0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It works for me but that line simply looks for the `INITIAL_REDUX_STATE` variable. I replaced that with the regular expression you were using, that seemed to work for you.

Comment: It works! Not sure why I was having trouble running it initially. Great job @Gregor!!

Comment: Sorry, I made yet another change as I realised that the products in the `INITIAL_REDUX_STATE` are differently formatted than those returned by the api. The format is now the same for all products.